# jQuery animate scrollTop not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have this simple jQuery autoscroll code on my website

```
    $('body[data-pagecontroller="profile"],body[data-pagecontroller="search"]').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ipsLayout_body").offset().top -65
}, 1000);
```

Basically, a simple Auto scroll to ipsLayout_body if the selectors exists within the body, While it works fine on Microsoft Edge, Chrome, Opera but not on  IE9 and firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Firefox has some issues with data- attributes and the animation, however I always use "html, body" to animate to the element I want, like this:

```
/* IF body[data-pagecontroller="profile"] OR
 body[data-pagecontroller="search"] Exists */
if($('body[data-pagecontroller="profile"]').length > 0 || $('body[data-pagecontroller="search"]').length > 0){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#ipsLayout_body').offset().top -65 },1000);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Leo.